What is the simplest classical force field to set up?
What is the simplest force field to set up?
I need to generate the potential energy of some conformers of amino acids and ligands in xyz files. I am not too concerned about the force field other than it should give comparable results to traditional force fields. What really matters is that it is easy to set up a calculation and accepts xyz/extxyz file inputs.

xTB package has a GFN-FF forcefield that can be used with an xyz file (it auto-builds the topolgy).

In order to run a molecular dynamics simulation, or a molecular mechanics calculation, you will need at least the following information:

System coordinates
Force field definitions
Molecular topology for each species present in the simulation/calculation

If I understood your question correctly, you have 1/3 of the required files at the moment (the coordinates). You should then select which force field you want to use. I have no idea how a 'simple' force field and a 'traditional' force field differ, as they are all quite simple in the end.
I would recommend spending some time on Google Scholar (or equivalent) to try and see if anyone has done similar research on the topic, and see which force fields and software packages they have used.
Finally, you will need to use the coordinates you have to derive molecular topologies. The way this is done is highly dependent on a) what simulation software you are intending to use, and b) what it is you are trying to model.
For example, GROMACS (which was a keyword in your question) comes with a built-in tool called 'pdb2gmx'. This tool takes in .pdb files, asks the user which force field they'd like to use, and outputs topologies. It is quite user-friendly and effective as long as the residues you're giving it are found in the residue database. In case you have something a bit more exotic that has not been pre-defined in residue databases you might have to do the conversion using other software. The ligands are very likely not incorporated in any package by default, so you will have to either find parameters for them from previous publications, or use an automated topology builder which is able to output topologies for the force field of your choosing.

Nice answer! But doesn't "molecular topology" mean specifying the bond-structure, i.e. atom-1 is bonded to atom-2 and atom-3, atom-2 is bonded to atom-3 and atom-4 and so on? In my experience, this one of the more complicated parts to get started. Some potentials like Lennard-Jones, Morse, Buckingham etc. don't require bond-topology. The only need atom types and parameters which I think is simpler to set up.

Indeed, there are force fields which only contain non-bonded terms. However, since OP was asking for potential energies of amino acids, and wanted to evaluate them using classical mechanics, I'd argue bonded terms are essential.

Ah, very good point.
